# SSL Performance Handshake size

Tags: ssl, iis

I have read many of the posts about performance. Finished all tests and still trying to find the source of the large handshake size that Wormly reports, 5307 bytes.

We have HTTP running on IIS7 so some suggested features like http2 or spdy cannot be implemented. Older machine and older Server 2008r2. However, ordering MS 2016 and upgrading server platform soon.

We have a CDN operating with some of our files. Comodo is the CA vendor.

Including link to WebPageTest Waterfall to get an opinion.

https://www.webpagetest.org/result/170620_C2_14TV/

Comment: What's your question and what relevance is the WebPageTest link you've given?

Comment: The link is to the test run on WebPageTest which shows errors/delays in handshakes. The question revolves around any insights StackFlow users may have

Comment: Where does it show that? I don't see the 5307 bytes you stated from beginning of the question. Are you asking for large bytes (which I can't understand where this is on the WPT link)? Or are you asking about the nearly 1 second delay to start getting first bytes of content back (which indeed looks to be slow but no idea if your homepage is a plain HTML page or is generated dynamically by a slow back end process)? Your question is completely unclear and thus impossible to answer.

Comment: Clicking on run 1, request 2 the ssl negotiation time is 56ms which is very good. It's the TTFB after this which is slow but, as I say, that depends on how the page is generated before being sent. If it's just serving a plain HTML file that seems very slow but if it's generated by a CMS or script then that might explain that but nothing you've provided will allow anyone to explain that.

Comment: BazzaDP, thanks, obviously, i have a lot to learn about SSL.  We continue to dig on the server side but have followed most blog posts to ensure proper setup.  The intial page is plain html but does have some data driven elements.  Will pursue and get back to you.

Comment: A large portion of the 5307 byte handshake is due to the 3 certificates (your + 2 intermediates) totaling up to 4331 bytes. This is OK and shouldn't be a cause for concern. As BazzaDP indicated, your server response times appear to be slow. Also look into enabling keepalive as indicated by Wormly.